# Python concatenate recursively strings in files

Tags: python, string, concatenation, permutation

I am a complete beginner in python, and I learned that you can concatenate easily strings, but now I have a specific need and I feel like an idiot because I don't know how to make it work.

What I need is to concatenate and permutate some words in `file1.txt` and some numbers in `file2.txt`

For example, in `file1.txt` there is a list of words (every word ends with a line break):

```
apple
banana
pear
```

and in `file2.txt` there is another list of words:

```
red
yellow
green
```

the idea is to concatenate each word from file1 to every single word in file2, resulting in something like this:

```
applered
appleyellow
applegreen
bananared
bananayellow
bananagreen
pearred
pearyellow
peargreen
```

And such result to be saved in another textfile.

I thought I could figure it out with my limited skills in python (from codecademy and udemy), but I don't know how to do it.

Comment: You need to break the problem down into its parts and, if needed, ask a separate question about each part.. What is the first problem you have? See [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: What I said:
I don't know how to make all the words from file1 to concatenate to the all the words in file2.
Thanks

Comment: Since your files are small and memoy will not be an issue, you can just read in all lines from both files. Then use two nested `for` loops, or a list comprehension to generate the list of permutations. Or you can take a look at [`itertools`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html).

Comment: @joe but which part of that don't you know? Forgetting about concatenation for the moment, can you open a file, read each line, and write it to another file? If not, ask a question about that instead. Or search. Or read the documentation. (hint: [read the documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/inputoutput.html#reading-and-writing-files)). Or is it reading a file into a list of lines? Or is it iterating over a list? There are many parts to solving your problem and you need to cut it up into small slices.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Code

Just use itertools.

```
import itertools

file1Input = [line.strip() for line in open('file1.txt').xreadlines()];
file2Input = [line.strip() for line in open('file2.txt').xreadlines()];


output = [x[0] + x[1] for x  in itertools.product(*[file1Input, file2Input])]
print(output)
```

**Explanation:** In the first and second Line I just open the file1.txt and file2.txt, read all lines,strip them, cause at the end there is always a linebreak and save them to a list. In the 3rd line of the code I make the permutation of both lists, and concatenate the permutation. In the 3rd line I just output the list

## Output List

```
['applered', 
 'appleyellow', 
 'applegreen', 
 'bananared', 
 'bananayellow', 
 'bananagreen', 
 'pearred', 
 'pearyellow', 
 'peargreen']
```

You can just easily put the `output` list into a file named output.txt

```
thefile = open("output.txt","wb")
for item in output:
  thefile.write("%s\n" % item)
```

or display it via

```
for x in output:
    print(x)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot!
I didn't know about itertools!
I'll tinker with it and learn some about it, thanks!

Comment: This is inefficient, and can be achieved with two simple loops over the input files.

Answer (score 0):

Concatenation is pretty simple, you can use '+' and do a little bit of cleaning first.

```
with open('File1') as f:
#Convert all file contents to an array
f1=f.readlines()
with open('File2') as f:
f2=f.readlines()
#If you print the above two arrays you will see, each item ends with a \n
#The \n symbolizes the enter key
#You need to remove the <n (used strip for this) and then you can concatenate easily
#Saving to a text file should be simple after the steps below
for file_1_item in f1:
      for file_2_item in f2:
          print file_1_item.strip('\n')+file_2_item.strip('\n')
```

Let me know if you want to know how to save it to a new text file as well :)

Comment: Both of you are awesome!
Thanks a lot!